# Xamarin xaml design view is not displaying in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**I am using Xamarin xaml in my visual studio 2013. I have installed Xamarin studio in my system.Then i open VS2013 creating a new project under Visual C#====>Mobile Apps ==>Blank App(Xamarion.Forms Portable). After that I created one xaml file but i could not see the design view in my page.I have attached the screen shot for your reference. Please kindly check this and give me a better solution to working on that.**

I cannot able to see my design view in xaml page also i cannot use any toolbox items,because its all disabled.

Comment: Please attach content from your xaml file to this post.

Comment: @user1295380 You saying ToolBox is disabled or it is closed?

Comment: Xamarin is false advertising: http://xamarin.com/visual-studio#designers - doesn't work out of the box for me either. Designer cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 3):

There is no designer for Xamarin Forms at the moment.